# eWASM vs PWASM: Are they complete independent? If so, in what ways are they different?

Tags: evm, wasm, ewasm

Understanding that eWASM is more like EVM 2.0 by replacing EVM with a subset of WASM instructions set.. What is the motivation of the PWASM project from Parity?

Notes:
https://medium.com/paritytech/why-we-believe-in-wasm-as-the-base-layer-of-decentralised-application-development-6196b8e3977e
https://github.com/aj07/design/commit/9d8ffee36f3b6c0fd4eb841c47183e4147c650b3

**EDIT**: https://youtu.be/_Nuw-hYjW64?t=1687
They are trying to achieve very similar things. But there is no official collaboration whatsoever at the moment.